# Proving that a Gaussian integer $a+bi$ with $a,b\neq0$ is composite in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if its norm $a^2+b^2$ is composite in $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

It is simple to show for any given composite sum of two squares, that there is at least one Gaussian composite with that norm, but more difficult to show that all Gaussian integers with that norm are composite.

How can we prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've established certain facts about the possible composite norms (i.e., you can't have primes $3 \pmod 4$ appear an odd number of times), then you can use Euclid's lemma in the Gaussian primes (which you can establish once you define the gcd): $p$ is prime iff when $p$ divides $ab$, it must divide either $a$ or $b$. So if you know that $p = \alpha\overline{\alpha}$ for some Gaussian prime $\alpha$ divides $x^2 + y^2$, you have that $\alpha$ must divide $p$, which divides $x^2 + y^2 = (x + iy)(x - iy)$. Hence, $\alpha$ divides $x + iy$ or $x - iy$. If the former, you're done. If the latter case, choose $\overline{\alpha}$.

That said, this is a lot of annoying casework and I'd rather just follow the usual path to getting a characterization of the Gaussian primes.

Comment: _"So if you know that $p=α\bar α$ for some Gaussian prime α divides $x^2+y^2$, ..."_ Isn't this is a circular argument? Basically you're saying that if we assume that x+yi is not a Gaussian prime... then x+yi is not a Gaussian prime.

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen not quite? I'm arguing that the _norm_ of $x + iy$ is divisible by some prime $p$, if it's composite. And if there happens to be a prime that is 2 or 1 mod 4, you can decompose $p$ into a product $\alpha\overline{\alpha}$. So by transitivity of division, $\alpha$ has to divide $x^2 + y^2 = (x + iy)(x - iy)$. The equivalent of Euclid's lemma finishes here.

Comment: Since $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$ and those factors are both prime, $x^2+y^2$ has no other possible factors, and I suppose you can extend that to higher composites. If two or more Gaussian integers have the same norm, then that norm, factorized in the Gaussian integers, must have all the same factors (up to conjugation) as all of the original numbers, squared. I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Proof by contradiction.

Suppose $x^2+y^2$ is composite in $\mathbb Z$ with non-zero $x$ and $y$. And suppose $x+yi$ is a Gaussian prime.

Let $x^2+y^2=ab$ with $|a|>1$ and $|b|>1$. Then $x+yi$ divides either $a$ or it divides $b$. Without loss of generality assume that $x+yi$ divides $a$. Therefore $x-yi=\frac{a}{x+yi}b$, which must also be a Gaussian prime. This is only possible if $\frac{a}{x+yi}$ is a unit, implying that either $x=0$ or $y=0$. Contradiction.

So if $x^2+y^2$ is composite in $\mathbb Z$ with non-zero $x$ and $y$, then $x+iy$ is not a Gaussian prime.