# Proof that if $(a + bi) \mid (x − i)$ then $(a − bi)\mid (x + i)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

This question looks simple but I am not able to solve it.

My thought:

Since $(a + bi) \mid (x − i)$, we know $N(a + bi)\mid N(x - i)$. Then $(a^2 + b^2) \mid (x^2 + 1)$ but I am not sure what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are $a,b,x$ assumed to be integers? And while we're at it, just to be on the safe side, is $i^2=-1$?

Comment: Hint: $u|v$ iff $uw=v$ for whichever kind of $w$ suit your definition of $|$.

Comment: Conjugation works

Comment: Yes, a, b , x are all integers and i^2 = -1

Comment: If $w=uv$, then $\bar w = \bar u \bar v$.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks good so far.

Note that $a^2 + b^2 = (a + ib)(a - ib)$, and (as [The Phoenix](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1038520/the-phoenix) said in the comments), if $(x−i)=(a+bi)(u+iv)$, then  $(x+i)=(a−bi)(u−iv)$.

Perhaps you will find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808386/proving-that-a-gaussian-integer-abi-with-a-b-neq0-is-composite-in-mathbb) useful to look at as well.